# Vue directive is being triggered for other components that were not affected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a directive:

```
Vue.directive('autosave', {
    componentUpdated(el) {
        console.log(el);
    },
})
```

I have 2 elements (vuetify):

```
this is a wrapper around input
<v-text-field label="Field 1" v-model="model1" v-autosave></v-text-field>
<v-text-field label="Field 2" v-model="model2" v-autosave></v-text-field>
```

If I make a change to the first input, the directive for BOTH get called. Why is this? How can I make it so only the affected element is called?

Vue version: 2.5.3
Vuetify version: 1.0.0-beta.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions):

> `componentUpdated`: called after the containing component’s VNode and
> the VNodes of its children have updated.

It's being called because the containing component's VNodes are updated. You seem to be expecting it to work like an `input` or `change` event. Why aren't you using [v-on](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on)?

What you should probably do is put a [`watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on your variables.

Comment: I get tunnel vision sometimes... This is probably one of the worst cases I've had so far... I was trying to figure out how I can DRY up some code and I ended up here. The thing is that I want to many different forms/fields (my app deals with many different models). Do you have any suggestions on how I should approach this problem? If not I'll just go ahead and go with `@change` or `@input`.

Comment: Look at [Vue.extend](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend). You can make a version of `v-text-field` with the autosave feature.